# What do you call a person who has had sex reassignment surgery?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, social-gender

OK, if a man or woman has changed their gender through surgery, what should we call them?

Can we call them  *transgender people*?

According to Google, **transgender** (adj) means "*denoting or relating to a person whose self-identity does not conform unambiguously to conventional notions of male or female gender.*" [Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:Transgender)

So, in that case, **transgender** does not tell us whether that person transformed his or her sex through surgery or not? Maybe he or she was born without his or her gender identified.

Comment: apparently "transsexual" may at one point have been used with this meaning. I don't mean this as a recommendation to use the word today. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsexual#Relationship_of_transsexual_to_transgender

Comment: Please tell us how you need to use this word; it's a requirement for single-word requests. (It could be as simple as an example sentence.)

Comment: I'd wager that the person would want to be called "a woman" or "a man"

Comment: [Transsexual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AR6wKRWFOoE&spfreload=10)

Comment: Surgery does not change a persons gender, as gender is a psychological concept. Surgery changes the persons sexual characteristics, or just 'sex'. See [the genderbread man](http://itspronouncedmetrosexual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Genderbread-Person-3.3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**transgender** is an umbrella term that refers to anybody who has a gender identity different to their at-birth sex, regardless of whether they have had sex reassignment surgery or not.

**transsexual** refers to somebody who *has* had sex reassignment surgery.

Transgender people will typically refer to themselves as the *gender* they identify with.

For example a person that has male genitalia but identifies as a woman, will introduce themselves as  a *transgender woman*.

For further clarity transsexuals might prefix with a 'male-to-female' or 'mtf'. eg. 'I'm a male-to-female transsexual woman'.

Here's some more information here: http://www.diffen.com/difference/Transgender_vs_Transsexual

To answer your specific questions:

1. People who have had sex reassignment surgery are transgender. People who *have not* had sex reassignment surgery are also transgender.
2. If someone identifies as transgender, they are providing no clue as to whether they have had sex reassignment surgery or not.
3. You can refer to someone that has had sex reassignment surgery as *transsexual*.

Comment: Point 3 seems misleading to me. You literally "can" refer to the person this way; you also literally "can" refer to them as a zucchini. The question is, should you? The term "transsexual" is controversial. Some people *identify* as transsexual; others do not. If the person does not identify as transsexual, it will generally be taken as rude (or in some social contexts, completely unacceptable) to refer to them with this term, even if they fit the definition.

Comment: so is it ok to say "*She is a transsexual person*" or "*a transsexual woman*". But if that is the case, then does it mean "*she was a female previously and became a male after surgery*" or "*she was a male previously and became a female after surgery*". A bit confused!!!

Comment: @sumelic, transsexual mean "*a person who has undergone treatment in order to acquire the physical characteristics of the opposite sex.*" https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20transsexual

Comment: @Tom: since you are using the present-tense "is" in that sentence, as well as female pronouns, the person is definitely female at the present time.

Comment: @Tom: besides the literal meaning of words, I assume you are also concerned with their social appropriateness? My point is simply that this is an area where people often take offense at certain terminology, even if it is technically accurate.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article I linked to: "Another reason for objecting to the term transsexual is the concern that it implies something to do with sexuality, when it is actually about gender identity. For example, Christine Jorgensen, the first widely-known person to have sex reassignment surgery (in this case, male to female), rejected transsexual and instead identified herself in newsprint as trans-gender, on this basis."

Comment: @dwjohnston: you link says that transsexual "often" refers to a person who has had surgery, which implies that this is not always the case.

Comment: I speak Vietnamese & in Vietnamese saying "transsexual" is a bit offended but the media still uses it. And people use it in everyday conversation but not talking directly to the transsexual people cos it could be unpolite or offended

Answer (score 2):

We would call them either a man or woman, whichever they identify with.

Comment: I think the original poster is actually looking for a term that would cover both men and women who have undergone one of these surgeries, and only men and women who have undergone one of these surgeries.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @dwjohnston is good, it is not entirely accurate.

The term ***transgender*** covers the wider range of people who do not fit the cis-gender binary of just "male" and "female".  This can include people who are intersex, transsexual, gender-queer and agender.  Please note that these are all *adjectives*.  A transgender person is not "a transgender".

The term ***transsexual*** literally means "to change sex from one to another".  Someone may be a transsexual *without* having sex reassignment surgery (also knows as gender confirmation surgery) to change their *primary* sex characteristics, but may be on a regime of hormones to change the *secondary* sex characteristics to align their body more closely with their identified gender.  This term applies to both transsexual men and women.

Not every transsexual person needs or requires surgery.  The correct terms are:

- ***Non-operative transsexual***: Someone who has or is using hormone replacement (such as oestrogen for trans women or testosterone for trans men), but does not feel the need to have sex reassignment surgery.
- ***Pre-operative transsexual***: Someone who requires surgery to feel complete but has not yet had the procedure.
- ***Post-operative transsexual***: Someone who has had sex reassignment or gender confirmation surgery.

Again, all of these terms apply to trans men and trans women.  For more information, refer to the [World Professional Association for Transgender Health Standards of Care V7](http://www.wpath.org/site_page.cfm?pk_association_webpage_menu=1351&pk_association_webpage=3926).

Of course, if you are wondering what you should address someone as who is transgender, the rule of thumb is to address them as the gender they are presenting as, or what term/pronouns they *ask* you use.